# Okhttp3 Base URL for calling

Tags: java, okhttp

I am using an OkHttp Client for my Webservice call, its working successfully with JAVA Main function and returning response.

Now, I want to call this client from Postman; but I dont know what URL Shall i call? Like in jersey we create a base URL from @PATH annotation in Spring we use @service. What shall be done in okhttp to create a base url to call? Please help.

```
    public String soapCaller() throws IOException, JSONException  {

        Response response = null;
try {
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=0146b9a4-7e99-4c83-8e9e-6049cfec55da&client_secret=cJ5nD0yJ4fV8eM1nU4tK2yI5wQ0lG6iE7cP5bD4lQ8dB0jS6pV&scope=ABLApis");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://uat-api.abl.com/abl-api/uat/oauth2/token")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .addHeader("accept", "application/json")
  .build();
 response = client.newCall(request).execute();
}

catch(Exception e)
{
    logger.info("e: " + e);
}
return response.toString();
    }
    }
```

with Jersey Annotations

```
    @GET
    @Path("/fundTransfer")
    @Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String soapCaller() throws IOException, JSONException  {

        /////////////////////////////



        Response response = null;
try {
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=0146b9a4-7e99-4c83-8e9e-6049cfec55da&client_secret=cJ5nD0yJ4fV8eM1nU4tK2yI5wQ0lG6iE7cP5bD4lQ8dB0jS6pV&scope=ABLApis");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://uat-api.abl.com/abl-api/uat/oauth2/token")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .addHeader("accept", "application/json")
  .build();
 response = client.newCall(request).execute();
}

catch(Exception e)
{
    logger.info("e: " + e);
}




///////////////////////////////////////////



return response.toString();
    }
    }
```

Comment: client.newCall(request), your url is in the request https://github.com/square/okhttp

Comment: "Now, I want to call this client from Postman" - how will you make a call to 'Client'? Is it a typo?

Comment: No, I want to ask that I have written this code and when I call this SoapCaller function from main function it works like a charm. But now, I have deployed this code on Weblogic server and want to make a remote call from postman to this code, What URL shall I enter there?

Comment: @Viet Please, explain a bit, I didnt get your words

Comment: I think you mix up some concepts. Jersey, as well as Spring, are web backend frameworks, thus they "listen" for incoming HTTP requests. OkHttpClient is a library and as already defined in the name, it's basically a client. A client does requests to a (HTTP) service, it does, however, not listen on incoming calls.

Comment: Actually, my client send request to the URL, thats fine. But I have to access this code from my postman, thats what my query is; How can I access it? do i have to use any annotation to set its calling path?

Comment: Now please check this code of mine [updated in my question], I have written this with okhttp client and jersey annotations; but its returning 400 error when I deploy it on weblogic. But when I access it through main method than its running like a charm.